# Direct pre-decoded threading in instruction set translator / emulator

Tags: emulation, interpreter

I have written a full system simulator / emulator of a RISC style processor (and all the peripherals). Currently, it is using an indirect threaded emulation loop. I.e. all the instruction footers are something in the style of:

```
pc += 4;
inst = loadWord(mem, pc);
instp = decodeTable[opcode(inst)];
goto *instp
```

This is performing quite well, I get around 70-80 MIPS on a modern machine when booting Linux, which is quite good.

However, I am looking at moving to a direct predecoded threaded interpreter model, that is something that looks as follows:

```
tPC += 1;
instp = predecodeMem[tPC].operation;
goto *instp;
```

The pre-decoding is not much of a problem in itself, it is just the replacement of the existing decoder and the addition of some shadow memory. My main problem with this is related to self modifying code (or semi-self modifying code).

In the simple case we can just allocate the predecode pages lazily when pages are visited which have not been executed before. The software TLB is then purged from all the entries to ensure we go through the memory simulation system on the next write to that page and thus, writes to executable pages will have to update the decode info as well which cost in performance, but as this is rare we should have no problem with it (also we can speed this up by adding sub page executable bits computed at runtime).

The problem here is about a long term code discovery when pages are reused by the operating system running inside the emulator. For example a memory page may be allocated by the Linux kernel, assigned as code for one process. Next time a process is created, the page may be allocated as data, but in the scheme just described this cause problems since the now pure data page will have to go through rather slow predecoding on every byte write.

Some current ideas, but non of these I find particularly nice, i.e. they all have significant drawbacks:

- Use mprotect() when executing a page and intercept the protection faults with signal handlers. This slows down writes alot and makes multithreaded multicore emulation a pain.
- When writing, instead of updating the predecode info, we flush the soft TLB translations related to code execution and flip a bit about the page being dirty. This should then slow down code execution on that page, but at least reads and writes are fast. Problem is of-course that the next time the page is reused as executable instead of data we have the same problem.
- Move to a smaller predecode-cache where a limited amount of pages with predecode info are kept. The pages age and are evicted based on an LRU policy or something similar. This approach penalise applications which have a fixed memory layout however (i.e. many embedded applications).

I find that the literature is seriously lacking on discussions on this topic. What general methods exist that can age pages when they are no longer used so that we for example clear the execute bit and the predecode memory associated with the page?

Comment: In an interpreter, you are choosing what to do based on each emulated instruction, so why would the OS executable flags matter?  Is this really just a virtualization layer rather than an emulator?  How are decodeTable[] and predecodeMem[] defined?  In the first section of code, it looks as though opcode(...) returns a pointer to a handler that (I think?) is executed by "goto *pinst" - how are these instruction handlers defined, and in what language is your emulator written?

Comment: Most of the instructions are implemented in a custom language that is then converted to LLVM IR.

Comment: The problem with a pre-decode based solution is that when a write instruction writes to predecoded memory, not only do we need to commit to the "normal" memory, but also to the pre-decode memory. We could do this at every write to such pages, but this would mean that the pages do not get reclaimed as non-predecoded-pages when say an application stops executing.

Mprotect would be used to set read and write attributes in this case. For example an "executable" page will be read by the emulator, thus it should be readable, but we must special case writes to ensure that the pages are wprot.

Comment: So, is your emulator implemented using LLVM IR, or are you using the intermediate representation to execute the actual code written for your RISC architecture?  Also, more generally, what is the speed you are trying to attain, and what are the constraints that are imposed on you (i.e. can you add memory and more CPUs to help, or are you limited to a specific hardware platform)?

Comment: The IR is driving the emulator loop and the instruction semantics. Nice thing is that the IR is binary translation compatible for the future. Anyhow, yes, it is possible to add new architectures and to implement your own memory models (though, the default RAM model is probably good enough for most people). Currently reaching around 80-90 MIPS on a 2.5 GHz host, which is quite good for an interpreter, but I want more  So pre-decoded translation is a good way to achieve higher performance with little effort, also it is easier to make it do stuff like code coverage and cache simulation.

Comment: Is self-modifying code common in your model, or will it be rare?  If self-modifying code is common in your model, you probably won't gain much from pre-decoded instructions no matter how you do it.  If self-modifying code is rare, you might check whether your pre-translator can indicate whether a code page is eligible for pre-translation, since the pre-translation step should be able to detect self-modifying code.  Or, you could mimic how CPUs handle execution context changes - flush the entire decoding pipeline and begin all over again, at huge cost for hopefully rare changes.

Comment: Modifying code will occur when a boot loader loads code into memory, when an existing OS reuse old code pages for new processes and when some one writes a linker script that does not page align the data and text sections... (this will mean the page with associated predecode info is modified), that is, most of the cases are not literally self modifying code but must still be treated as such. I suppose that it will be rare to run a JIT inside the emulator, but it seems to be a case that should at-least work albeit with loss of performance.